# Populating a TDBTest box Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi-xe2

So, what I am trying to accomplish is when the number in one field is >= to a certain number then the field I want to populate will do a comparison and populate, or not depending on the condition. If the result is true the field is populated fine, but if the result is false it still performs the calculation and populates the field with " -4. I have worked trying to fix the problem for over a week. Can't seem to get it done. My variable 'total' is declared an integer.

I understand that I am comparing text and integers and that I should not compare that way and that I should convert the text to integer then calculate, but every time I try to convert something to integer I get an error code telling me that it is not a valid integer. I don't have enough experience to figure this out.

I am creating a four week budget. I buy an item, calculate how many portions there are and spread the cost through the four weeks. If there are more portions than 4 what is left over after the four week that number is calculated and automatically entered in the "leftover" field. In this code everything works perfectly, except the last if statement.It calculates and enters the data correctly, if the portions are more than 4. If they are less than 4 it writes a"-4" in the field. I cannot see my error. That is where I need help.

My Code:

```
procedure TForm1.costperChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  Total: integer;
  total1: double;
begin
  Total1 := tblCosts.FieldByName('Cost').Asfloat / tblCosts.FieldByName('servings').Asfloat ;
  costper.Text:= floattostr(total1);

  if serv.Text >= '1' then
    wk1.Text:= costper.Text
  else
    wk1.Text:= '';

  if serv.Text >= '2' then
    wk2.Text:= costper.Text 
  else
    wk2.Text:= '';

  if serv.Text >= '3' then
    wk3.Text:= costper.Text
  else
    wk3.Text:= '';

  if serv.Text >= '4' then
    wk4.Text:= costper.Text 
  else
    wk4.Text:= '';

  if serv.Text >= '5' then
    total:= strtoint(serv.Text);

  total:= total - 4;
  left.Text:= inttostr(total);
end;
```

Comment: Don't compare strings. Convert to integer and compare integers. Other than that, I have really no idea what you expect your code to do, and how it fails to meet your expectations. Can't you be clearer.

Comment: I am, as far as I know I did convert to integers and I amcomparing intege. I don't have enough experience and knowledge to be much clearer. I want the field othertextbox to be empty of the comparison is false.  It will repopulate correctly if the comparison is true. It doesn't remove the data if the result is false. Instead it populates the field with "-4". I want that to go away.

Comment: I don't know what that means. There is no error. It simply populates field with "-4" if the result is false.

Comment: You only showed an excerpt of code. We can't see it all. You perform one comparison. A text comparison. Read the code. Learn about indentation. Not the first time that message has been presented to you.

Comment: okay I apologize about indentation. I haven't been here, or worked on programing for a very long time. I help victims of violent crimes. All that negativity from the victims takes a heavy toll and programing helps me unwind from it, I will try to do better in the future.

Comment: I fixed your indentation. Again. Please look closely at the code. Look at the code after the final if. Only one statement is attached to the if. The next two execute unconditionally.

Comment: I have been working on it since your comments. I added a begin/end to the if and that created a fatal error."serv.Text >= '5' then begin". Then I added an end else at the end of the first block  "left.Text:= inttostr(total) end else" Then I added another if statement " serv.text <= '4' then total:= 0 ;". finally I asigned the value of total to serv.text. Now while it doesn't make the field nil, it does change the value to "0" when the number in serv.text is less than 5 and that is good enough. Thank you so much for your help. How do I assign the credit for this success to you?

Comment: Don't worry about it.